# Start a Xenial lxc container on a Trusty machine

Tags: 14.04, systemd, lxc, container

I'm having trouble starting a xenial lxc container on my trusty machine.

I had no problems installing the container (by following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html), which also allowed me to create and start some other trusty containers successfully), but when I try to start it I get this error:

```
async@riff:~$ sudo lxc-start -n jenkins-slave-xenial
Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Permission denied
[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.
Freezing execution.
```

Based on an advice from the debian lxc wiki page, I tried to follow [this advice](https://github.com/debops/ansible-lxc/issues/15#issuecomment-87253770). It changed the error, but did not fix it:

```
async@riff:~$ sudo lxc-start -n jenkins-slave-xenial
lxc-start: cgmanager.c: cgm_setup_limits: 1378 call to cgmanager_set_value_sync failed: invalid request
lxc-start: cgmanager.c: cgm_setup_limits: 1381 Error setting cgroup use:lxc/jenkins-slave-xenial limit type use
lxc-start: start.c: lxc_spawn: 952 failed to setup the cgroup limits for 'jenkins-slave-xenial'
lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1121 failed to spawn 'jenkins-slave-xenial'
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 341 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 345 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

I'm lost here. Am I missing something to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install lxc from `trusty-backports`.

i.e. `sudo apt install -t trusty-backports lxc lxc-templates`

You'll want to stop your existing hung container (`lxc-stop --kill --name jenkins-slave-xenial`) and then try starting it again.

See https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/685 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1590547 for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by adding to the container config:

lxc.mount.auto = cgroup:mixed

Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, Trusty Tahr, packages:

- lxc                2.0.8-0ubuntu1~14.04.1
- lxc-templates      2.0.8-0ubuntu1~14.04.1